# How can I get a real string value from Future<String> in widget?

Tags: flutter

Instead of expected string value I get the `Instance of Future<String>` in my widget:
(in the second line of winget should be a string value of 373,8)

```
(_rapport.isNotEmpty && _rapport.length == 3)
  ? Text((_distortion(_rapport, widget.printer)).toString()) // this function return Future<String>
  : const Text(''), // rapport is empty
```

The function is:

```
Future<String> _distortion(String rapport, String printer) async {
    final String record = await _getRecord(rapport);

    print('record: ${record.toString()}'); // this gives me an expected valid output

    final List row = record.toString().split(';');
    final String d1 = row[1]; // tachys
    final String d2 = row[3]; // onyx

    switch (printer) {
      case 'Tachys':
        {
          print('distortion: $d1'); // output: distortion: 373,8
          return d1;
        }
        break;

      default:
        {
          print('distortion: $d2');
          return d2;
        }
    }
  }
```

How can I get real value from Future in widget?

Comment: As you can't use async in `build` always do all your async work outside of `build`. When the time comes to build the actual widget, pass your future/async computation to `FutureBuilder` and voilà. For a detailed explanation of why `FutureBuilder` and how it works under the hood [here is an explanation](https://flutterigniter.com/build-widget-with-async-method-call/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do that is using **FutureBuilder()** widget .

Change your **build** function to following

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
      future : _distortion()
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return new Text('Loading....');
            default:
              if (snapshot.hasError)
                return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              else
                return (_rapport.isNotEmpty && _rapport.length == 3)
          ? Text(snapshot.data) 
          : (_rapport.isNotEmpty && _rapport.length < 3)
          ? const Text('wrong rapport')
          : const Text(''), // rapport is empty
   );
          }

},
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you must to add async await when you call (_distortion) function as below:

```
(_rapport.isNotEmpty && _rapport.length == 3)
  ? Text(await (_distortion(_rapport, widget.printer)).toString()) // this function return Future<String>
  : (_rapport.isNotEmpty && _rapport.length < 3)
      ? const Text('wrong rapport')
      : const Text(''),
```

Comment: This gives me syntax error in editor: the method `await` is not defined for this class.

Comment: You should to add (async) in your outer function

Answer (score 0):

Either you can call the method in `initState()` and set the value else use `FutureBuilder` for handling future value.You can have a look at the [documentation of FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)